# Links not on their original position in this dropdown menu I made

Tags: html, css

I have made this dropdown menu but I'm stuck now and need your help.

There are 2 problems.

The links in the submenu aren't in their `li` parent, instead they are positioned lower as you can see in [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xdgk37aa/1/).

The other problem is that there is supposed to be a full page width background below the main menu, as high as the currently viewed submenu. Like this:
[image: Navigation concept]

I'm not even sure how to do this, i have tried some things but just cant achieve this. If you know of a similar menu like this please link to it maybe I can figure it out after seeing their code.

Here is the HTML:

```
    <nav class="main-nav">
    <ul class="clearfix">
      <li class="small"></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">a us</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">asdsds</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">sdds</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">dssde</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">dsdsdsf</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">ssdfd</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">afsdfs</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">bmbnmb</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">cvbcvb</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">dfgdhdfg</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">erterte</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">dsfs</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">dfsdfsd</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">dsfsdfsd</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">sdfsdf</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">dsfsdfdsf</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">sdfsdfsdf</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">sdfsdfds</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">sdfsdfsdf</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">sdfdsfsd</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">sdf</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">sds</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">sdds</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">sdfds</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">sdds</a></li>
      <li class="small"></li>
     </ul> 
  </nav>
```

And the CSS:
        /* Navigation */

```
    nav.main-nav ul{
      padding: 0;
      background-color: #f6a000;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    }

    nav.main-nav > ul > li{
      display: inline-block;
      width: 16%;
      height: 60px;
      float: left;
      line-height: 60px;
      text-align: center;
      border-right:1px solid #fff;
    }

    nav.main-nav ul > li:last-child{
      border: none;
    }

    nav.main-nav > ul > li > a{
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      display: inline-block;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    nav.main-nav ul li:hover{
      background-color: #F67900;
    }

    nav.main-nav ul li.small{
      width: 2%;
    }

    nav.main-nav li ul{
      position: absolute;
      width: 16%;
      z-index: 100;
      /*left: 0;*/
      display: none;

    }

    nav.main-nav li:hover ul{
      display: block;

    }

    nav.main-nav li li{
      display: block;
      float: none;
      width: 100%;
      height: 20px;
      background-color: #F67900;
    }

    nav.main-nav li li a{
      line-height: 20px;
      color: #fff;
      height: 20px;
      display: inline-block;

    }
    nav.main-nav li li:hover a{
      color: #F35900;
    }

    .clearfix:after {
       content: " "; /* Older browser do not support empty content */
       visibility: hidden;
       display: block;
       height: 0;
       clear: both;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not my code, but I found another fiddle that does pretty much what you're looking for (with different styles.  Instead of reinventing the wheel, I decided to link this:

http://jsfiddle.net/4MEWL/1/

and the CSS:

```
body { overflow-x: hidden; } /* trick from css-tricks comments */

/* FIRST LEVEL */

.nav > ul > li { 
    display: inline-block; 
    position: relative; 
    padding: 3px 10px 3px 0;
    z-index: 100;
}

/* SECOND LEVEL */

.nav > ul > li > ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    padding: 0 1000em; /* trick from css-tricks comments */
    margin: 0 -1000em; /* trick from css-tricks comments */
    z-index: 101;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    background: rgba(255, 240, 240, 0.8);
}

.nav > ul > li:hover > ul {    
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}

.nav > ul > li > ul > li {
    padding: 3px 0;
}

.nav > ul > li:hover .drop {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```